# Is a finite group simple iff it is strongly linearly primitive?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

A finite group $G$ is *strongly linearly primitive* if every non-trivial complex irreducible representation is faithful.

A finite simple group is clearly strongly linearly primitive.

*Question*: Is the converse also true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. If a finite group $G$ isn't simple, it has some nontrivial quotient $G/H$ which has a nontrivial irreducible representation. This gives a nontrivial irreducible representation of $G$ which isn't faithful.

Comment: Nice! So we can generalize the concept of "finite simple group" to inclusion of finite groups as follows: the inclusion $(H \subset G)$ is called *simple* if  for all non-trivial irr. complex repr. $V$ of $G$ such that $V^H \neq 0$ then $G_{(V^H)} = H$ (see the notation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1437706/84284)). One can then looks for a generalization of the Jordan-Holder theorem.